# how to find the smallest parameter for trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry, parametric, parameter-estimation, parametrization

Find the smallest value of parameter $\alpha$ such that equation $${\mathrm{sin}}^{2}x \times  \mathrm{cos}2x + \alpha ({\mathrm{cos}}^{4}x - {\mathrm{sin}}^{4}x) = -10(2\alpha  + 1{)}^{2}$$ has at least one real solution.

simplifying the expression I got $${\mathrm2{sin}}^{4}x - \mathrm{sin}^{2}x(1-2a) - (a+40a^2 + 40a + 10) = 0 $$
And solved $$ (1-2a)^2 + 8(a + 40a^2 + 40a + 10) = 0 $$
At the end I have a = - 1/2. There is only 1 answer?

Comment: "$\alpha$" and "$a$" are different symbols.  During simplification, some $\alpha$ subexpressions seem to have transformed into $a$ subexpressions, but no definition for $a$ is given.  How did the $\alpha$s turn into $a$s?

Comment: @EricTowers, thanks for the remark. There is the α symbol in the task, but I thought it wouldn't be angle according to usual parameters exercises. Maybe I'm wrong. Is my solution right?

Comment: I couldn't say...  Your "simplification" is baffling: where did a second $\sin^4 x$ come from without a $\sin^2 x \cos^2 x$ also appearing? ... what is the source of the leading "$a + \cdots$" in the long parenthetical? ...

Comment: @EricTowers, it's trigonometric transformations like $${\mathrm{sin}}^{2}x \times  \mathrm{cos}2x + \alpha ({\mathrm{cos}}^{4}x - {\mathrm{sin}}^{4}x) = ({\mathrm{cos}}^{2}x - {\mathrm{sin}}^{2}x)({\mathrm{sin}}^{2}x + a) $$

Comment: I haven't bothered to check your arithmetic.  However, as a general rule, if you have an equation $f(a)\sin^4(x) + g(a)\sin^2(x) + h(a) = 0$, then you must find the minimum value of $a$ that satisfies the following two constraints: $~~$ [1] $~~[g(a)]^2 - 4f(a)h(a) \geq 0~~$ and $~~$ [2] $~~(-1) \leq \sin(x) \leq (1).$

Comment: Re previous comment, I intend that $D = g(a)^2 - 4f(a)h(a)$ and that $\displaystyle \sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2f(a)} \times \left[-g(a) \pm \sqrt{D}\right].$  Note that you must have that $0 \leq \sin^2(x) \leq 1.$

Answer (score 1):

To find solutions to the trigonometric equation that are real, we solve the equation with respect to $sin(x)^{2}$; we get two roots:

$sin(x)^{2}=-\frac{9|2\alpha+1|}{4}-\frac{2\alpha-1}{4}$,

$sin(x)^{2}=+\frac{9|2\alpha+1|}{4}-\frac{2\alpha-1}{4}$.

We impose that

$0≤sin(x)^{2}≤1$.

We then write the system:

$0≤-\frac{9|2\alpha+1|}{4}-\frac{2\alpha-1}{4}≤1$,

$0≤+\frac{9|2\alpha+1|}{4}-\frac{2\alpha-1}{4}≤1$.

The solution is:

$-\frac{3}{5}≤\alpha≤-\frac{2}{5}$.